# To set Contact Picture using Contact ID

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have a Bitmap and a Contact id. I want a function that takes these parameters and sets the Bitmap as the Contact picture of that id. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

try

Convert your bitmap into byteArray

```
Bitmap bit; // <-- put your bitmap here
ByteArrayOutputStream streamy = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
bit.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, streamy); 
byte[] photo = streamy.toByteArray();
```

and then

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
int photoRow = -1; 
String where = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " == " + 
    ContentUris.parseId(yourContectID) + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "=='" + 
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'"; 
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
        null, 
        where, 
        null, 
        null); 
int idIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data._ID); 
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){ 
    photoRow = cursor.getInt(idIdx); 
} 
cursor.close(); 
values.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 
        ContentUris.parseId(yourContectID)); 
values.put(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1); 
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, photo); 
values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, 
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE); 
if(photoRow >= 0){ 
    this.getContentResolver().update(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
            values, 
            ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = " + photoRow, null); 
    } else { 
        this.getContentResolver().insert(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
                values); 
    } 
}
```

don not forget to add permissions `WRITE_CONTACTS` and `READ_CONTACTS` in your `manifest file`

Comment: It is a copy paste thing. I have seen this post.

Comment: Where have you used the Contact ID?

Comment: you have not see `yourContectID` in the whole code? For your kind information it is the `Contact ID`. It is not the way you are asking questions here. you don't hire the `SO` to solve your home-works. Please make some effort to learn, and do some code before posting question here. and come with exact problem you are facing.